# How to pass multiple arguments to an Inputs onChange listener?

Tags: reactjs, input, onchange

I am using React hooks, not the class based approach.

So I have a Person component which has an Input element assigned to it. I need to pass the event(from which I extract the new/changed value) and an index to the listener function.

How can I pass both the event and the index?

```js
return (
            <Person
//other attributes
              change={renamePersonHandler.bind(this, (event, index))}
            />
          );
```

onChange listener.

```
   const renamePersonHandler = (event, id) => {
    // does stuff
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The Input element value is passed to the function automatically. It's enough to just bind it and specify the other argument.

```
     return (
            <Person
//other attributes
              change={renamePersonHandler.bind(this, person.id)}
            />
            );
```